# nhibernate +fluent +mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a table http://img36.imageshack.us/i/beztytuuszxq.png/ and mapping:

```
public class CategoryMap : ClassMap<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
        Table(FieldNames.Category.Table);
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.ShowInMenuBar).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.Parent).Column(FieldNames.Category.ID).Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.Articles).Cascade.All().Inverse().Table(FieldNames.Article.Table);
    }
}
```

The entity looks that:

```
public class Category : EntityBase
{
    public virtual int ID { set; get; }
    public virtual string Name { set; get; }
    public virtual Category Parent { set; get; }
    public virtual bool ShowInMenuBar { set; get; }
    public virtual IList<Article> Articles { set; get; }
}
```

When I want to save an Category object to db, when Parent property is set to null, I have exception:

`not-null property references a null or transient value CMS.Domain.Entities.Article.Category`

I cannot change the

```
public virtual Category Parent { set; get; }
```

line to

```
public virtual Category? Parent { set; get; }
```

or

```
public virtual Nullable<Category> Parent { set; get; }
```

because I have an error during compile:

`CMS.Domain.Entities.Category' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>'`

I don't know what to change to have possibility to save Category objects without parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a reference type Nullable (as it already is).  `Nullable<T>` (or `T?`) can only be used with a non-nullable value type (such as `int` or `DateTime`).

The error refers to CMS.Domain.Entities.Article.Category - the Category property in the Article class.  You haven't provided the map file for the Article entity, however I assume it maps the Category property and either specifies `Not.Nullable()` or doesn't specific `Nullable()`.

If the domain model allows for the Article entity to contain a null Category use `Nullable()` otherwise you need to set the category when creating/saving the Article:

```
Article.Category = aCategory;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't Nullable the Category is because Nullable is only meant for value types, and Category, by definition, is a reference type and therefore already can support nulls on properties defined as Category. Can you provide a full stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you are trying to save an article, (you specified inverse) therefore you need this:
Article.Category = category;